# regex: extract SVG path d attribute

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, svg, match

I have a source containing one SVG path:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" stroke="red" fill="grey"><path d="M 10 10 L 100 100 Q 200 50 300 100 A 80 50 20 1 0 400 600 Z" fill="none" stroke="red" stroke-width="5" /></svg>
```

it also can be single quoted

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" stroke="red" fill="grey"><path d='M 10 10 L 100 100 Q 200 50 300 100 A 80 50 20 1 0 400 600 Z' fill="none" stroke="red" stroke-width="5" />
```

I want the part between <path=start quote and finish quote.

```
M 10 10 L 100 100 Q 200 50 300 100 A 80 50 20 1 0 400 600 Z
```

I have tried (JS)

```
var result = svg_tag.match(/<path(.*?)>/g).map(function(val){
   return val.replace(/<path d="/g,'');
});
```

But it returns

```
[
  'M',                '10',
  '10',               'L',
  '100',              '100',
  'Q',                '200',
  '50',               '300',
  '100',              'A',
  '80',               '50',
  '20',               '1',
  '0',                '400',
  '600',              'Z"',
  'fill="none"',      'stroke="red"',
  'stroke-width="5"', '/>'
]
```

Comment: `var result = svg_tag.match(/\bd=(['"])(.*?)\1/)[2];` -- while I would typically advise strongly against using regex for XML, if your source is that consistent then it should be fairly straightforward.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol Thanks very much, Please make a formal answer and I will tick for your points.

Comment: You can also do: `document.querySelector("path").getAttribute("d")`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## `[ \w]{10,}`

This `RegExp` matches any substring at least `10` characters long containing only letters, numbers, spaces, and underscores.

```js
const regex = /[ \w]{10,}/;

const tag1 = '<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" stroke="red" fill="grey"><path d="M 10 10 L 100 100 Q 200 50 300 100 A 80 50 20 1 0 400 600 Z" fill="none" stroke="red" stroke-width="5" /></svg>';
const tag2 = `<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" stroke="red" fill="grey"><path d='M 10 10 L 100 100 Q 200 50 300 100 A 80 50 20 1 0 400 600 Z' fill="none" stroke="red" stroke-width="5" />`;

console.log(tag1.match(regex)[0]);
console.log(tag2.match(regex)[0]);
```